# Format one virtual disk in a RAID array?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid

In my machine I have two virtual disks handled by my RAID controller. They're mapped on Windows Server as my C: drive and my D: drive. I wish to wipe and reinstall a new version of windows server on C:. Can I wipe and reinstall the OS on that virtual disk without affecting the other virtual disk?

Comment: Yes, however you would need a boot system which understands your raid. For a hardware raid this is easy, but there are some solutions out there where the OS must assists.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual disk? What kind of RAID controller are we talking about?

Comment: @DanielB, I mean 4 physical disks have been RAID1+0 to make one virtual disk.

Comment: @DanielB Perc6i